# null value in foreign key field of sqlite table created from peewee

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, null, peewee

i use peewee as orm for sqlite in python and i created a table with a foreignkey field, which must accept null values but it doesn't do that - i always get the error: "An error occurred while committing the data: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed"

Here the python code for the peewee model (BaseModel) - as you see the relevant field "klasse" is set to "null=True", but a null value is not accepted:

```
class Lerngruppe(BaseModel):
    bezeichner = TextField(primary_key=True)
    
    # somtimes no group of pupils available (=> null=True)
    klasse = ForeignKeyField(
        Klasse, column_name="klasse_id", null=True)
    
    fach = ForeignKeyField(
        Fach, column_name="fach_id", null=False)
    
    lehrkraft = ForeignKeyField(
        Lehrkraft, column_name="lehrkraft_id", null=False)
    
    von = DateField(null=True)
    
    bis = DateField(null=True)
```

peewee then creates the following sqlite table (sqlite-DDL):

```
CREATE TABLE lerngruppe (
    bezeichner   TEXT        NOT NULL
                             PRIMARY KEY,
    klasse_id    TEXT,
    fach_id      VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
    lehrkraft_id VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    von          DATE,
    bis          DATE,
    notiz        TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        klasse_id
    )
    REFERENCES klasse (bezeichner),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        fach_id
    )
    REFERENCES fach (kuerzel),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        lehrkraft_id
    )
    REFERENCES lehrkraft (kuerzel) 
);
```

The foreign key points to the corresponding peewee model (BaseModel) "Klasse":

```
class Klasse(BaseModel):

    # target of the foreignkey
    bezeichner = TextField(primary_key=True)

    stammraum = ForeignKeyField(
        Raum, column_name="stammraum_id", null=True)

    klassenleitung = ForeignKeyField(
        Lehrkraft, column_name="klalei_id", null=True)

    coklassenleitung = ForeignKeyField(
        Lehrkraft, column_name="coklalei_id", null=True)
```

And the DDL for this model definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE klasse (
    bezeichner   TEXT          NOT NULL
                               PRIMARY KEY,
    stammraum_id VARCHAR (255),
    klalei_id    VARCHAR (5),
    coklalei_id  VARCHAR (5),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        stammraum_id
    )
    REFERENCES raum (name),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        klalei_id
    )
    REFERENCES lehrkraft (kuerzel),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        coklalei_id
    )
    REFERENCES lehrkraft (kuerzel) 
);
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question where the error is occurring. A couple things to check:

- make sure to drop the table before creating it. If peewee sees the table already exists, it won't re-create it.
- is the error occurring when you try to insert new data? if so the error message may indicate that the FK constraint is being violated by an unmatched primary-key rather than a NULL value
- what database are you using? I assume sqlite?

Can you share code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: to 1) the tables are new

Comment: OK solved. The problem is not peewee. We did some simple checks on the created database with sqlitestudio and there the errors occured. The error doesn't occur if we insert datasets over "insert_many" in peewee with lists of dictionaries. Next we tried to insert data  in sqlitestudio and - tata - works. But only if we use the sql window with the SQL-Statment INSERT INTO ... The data input in the table view in the GUI doesn't work...